# Void function error in c++

Tags: c++

So I have use the void function and put 5 parameters in it; 1. prompt for user input, 2. prompt for correct range of input, 3. integer variable used to store the the user input, 4. input should be smaller or equal to this value, 5. input should be greater or equal to this value.

I don't have a good understanding with this function but this is what I've got so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

// function declaration
void get_data(string, string, int&, int, int);


int main() 
{

int year;
string input_prompt;
string range_prompt;

get_data(input_prompt, range_prompt, year, 1970, 2020);

cout << "\nYour inputs are:\n";
cout << "..." << year  << "\n";

int month;
string input_prompt;
string range_prompt;

get_data(input_prompt, range_prompt, month, 1, 12);

cout << "..." << month << "\n";

....
return 0;
}

// function definition 
void get_data(string input_prompt, string range_prompt, int& input, int 
criteria_1, int criteria_2){

input_prompt = "Please enter the year: ";
range_prompt = "Invalid input. 1970 <= year <= 2020!";

criteria_1 = 1970;
criteria_2 = 2020;

.....
```

}

I'm getting an error message every time i try to run this. I know this is because the value in the void function keeps changing and there is no reference to these in the main function ... or something like that. How can I fix this?

UPDATE:

What I'm saying is that the void function is used to collect year, month, day, hour, min and second from the user in the specified range.

The main function will display the collection of the data in the void function.

Output should be:

```
Please enter the year: 2013  
Please enter the month: 1  
Please enter the day: 24  
Please enter the hour: 13  
Please enter the minute: 55  
Please enter the second: 45  

Your inputs are:  
Year = 2013  
Month = 1  
Day = 24  
Hour = 13  
Minute = 55  
Second = 45
```

I'm alright with getting the input from the user. Now I need to collect all these inputs and display them on the screen. That's the part where I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: What is your question?  You don't understand this code, you want to make sure it is correct?

Comment: What you want from the SO?

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/*Acode for swaping two values using void function*/
int z=0, x, y;
void func(int& x, int& y){
   cout<<"Enter the value of x: ";
   cin>>x;
   cout<<"Enter the value of y: ";
   cin>>y;
   z=x;
   x=y;
   y=z;
}

int main()
{
   func(x,y);
   cout<<"The value of x after swaping is: "<<x<<endl;
   cout<<"The value of y after swaping is: "<<y<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: A block of code without any explanation is not an answer. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)